# Am fetching data from database i need to pass variable in my query.but am not getting how to pass variable in query

Tags: mysql, python

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con=mdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="yogi@123", db="wisdomjo_db2011")
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT suggestion,related FROM `auto_related` WHERE suggestion!='' AND type='S' GROUP BY suggestion")
numrows = cur.rowcount
for x in xrange(0,numrows):
    row = cur.fetchone()
    cur.execute("SELECT suggestion,LOWER(REPLACE(suggestion,' ','')) as suggest,related FROM `auto_related` WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(suggestion,' ',''))=%s  AND type='S' ORDER BY Id LIMIT 0,6",(row[0]))
    data=cur.fetchall()
    print data
```

Comment: please anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Do the `JOIN` in SQL, not with a client-side loop.  Cutting down on the number of round-trips to the server helps; cutting down on the number of queries to parse and execute helps, even though the resulting query is more complex.

But the real slowdown is not having the result of `LOWER(REPLACE(suggestion,' ',''))` as an indexed column in the table.